# Can't display window with WinAPI

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, directx

I know this is a boring question, and I have done it million times before, but I can't display a simple window in a WinAPI program that I write. It later uses DirectX to draw on the window, but I have debugged the program and it just can't show the window even before all DirectX stuff starts executing. I only see the program icon on taskbar, but there's no window.

Here's the piece of code that deals with window creation.

```
WNDCLASSEX wc;
    ZeroMemory(&wc, sizeof(wc));
    wc.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wc.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wc.lpfnWndProc = (WNDPROC)WndProc;
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.lpszClassName = title.c_str();
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wc.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wc.hIcon = 0;
    wc.hIconSm = 0;
    wc.hbrBackground = 0;
    wc.lpszMenuName = 0;

    if(!RegisterClassEx(&wc))
    {
        debug << "Failed to register window class." << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }

    DWORD dwStyle, dwExStyle;
    dwStyle = WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE;
    dwExStyle = WS_EX_APPWINDOW | WS_EX_WINDOWEDGE;

    AdjustWindowRectEx(&windowRect, dwStyle, FALSE, dwExStyle);

    int wwidth = windowRect.right - windowRect.left;
    int wheight = windowRect.bottom - windowRect.top;

    debug << "Screensize: " << wwidth << "x" << wheight << std::endl;
    debug << "Creating program window..." << std::endl;

    HWND hWnd = CreateWindowExW(dwExStyle, wc.lpszClassName, title.c_str(), dwStyle | WS_CLIPCHILDREN | WS_CLIPSIBLINGS, 0, 0, wwidth, wheight, NULL, NULL, hInstance, 0); 

    if(!hWnd)
    {
        debug << "Error occured while trying to display the window.\n";
        return false;
    }

    ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_SHOW);
    UpdateWindow(hWnd);
```

I'm in desperation. I'm starting to thing there's something wrong with my programming environment, libraries etc. I'm on VS2012/Win7, and the standard c++ compiler that comes with VS.

**EDIT**
WindowRect is here

```
RECT windowRect;
    windowRect.left = 0;
    windowRect.right = g_engine->getScreenWidth(); //800
    windowRect.top = 0;
    windowRect.bottom = g_engine->getScreenHeight(); //600
```

And here's DefWindowProc

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc (HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
if(msg == WM_DESTROY)
    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Comment: Did you have any errors and use `GetLastError`? Does `title` live on for the entire program, so that `title.c_str()` doesn't become a dangling pointer?

Comment: As you can see, I'm writing logs before/after critical operations. My log files show nothing, and I've debugged the code and title.c_str() seems to be living during CreateWindowExW.

Comment: Do you call DefWndProc in your WinProc returning the correspondent LRESULT? Creation failure is mostly due to WM_NCCREATE returning false instead of true

Comment: Where is `windowRect` defined, and what values does it contain before the call to `AdjustWindowRectEx()`?

Comment: Is that your actual `WndProc()`? Then @Emilio is right, and your compiler should (at least) warn you that not all code paths in there return a value.

Comment: Oh, I guess I understood. That's what happens when you code at 3 AM. My WndProc is a mess :D

Comment: Emilio, thanks for pointing out. Strangely, my compiler didn't warn about anything. Please add an answer. I will accept it.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: Both MSVC and MinGW warn about missing returns only if -Wall (or -W3) is specifyed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most of the times I went into this problem was a bad return value from `WinProc`.

Your `WinProc` will probably call `DefWndProc` without returning its return value.
This makes `WM_NCCREATE` to be treated as returning false (instead of true, as it should), causing the creation process to stop.

A proper windowproc should be

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc (HWND h, UINT u, WPARAM w, LPARAM l)
{
  if(...) {}
  else if(...) {}
  else if(...) {} //prematurely return if you don't want the default behavior

  return DefWndProc(h,u,w,l);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your wndProc looks wrong:

```
if(msg == WM_DESTROY) // <-- you should remove it and let system handle default messages 
    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
```